# Sometimes my computer won't boot

Tags: boot, motherboard

Occassionaly I have a really weird problem where my pc won't boot. 
I'll turn on the computer, fans start spinning, lights come one, but a few seconds later, the fans power down and nothing happens. I can see some RGB lights inside the case, so it's still on, but it's not doing anything. 
My monitors will go into standby because they're not receiving a signal, and my wired keyboard doesn't have power.

So far the only remedy I've found is to unplug the power cable and leave it out for at least an hour. After that it boots normally again. 
I haven't timed it exactly, but it's at least 45 minutes. If I plug it in after 30 minutes, nothing happens, and I have to wait another hour..

So far I've been unable to find a cause. It seems to happen sporadically, at random.
At first I thought it might have something to do with sleep mode or standby, but I've disabled those in Windows, and it also happens after the pc has been turned off normally.

My specs are: 
Gigabyte X570 Aorus Elite (AM4)
AMD Ryzen 7 3700x
32GB DDR4 1064 Mhz
ADATA SX8200PNP 1TB M.2 SSD
AMD Radeon RX6800

Does anyone have an idea what this could be? Broken motherboard perhaps?

Cheers,
CJ

Comment: You need to get machine serviced by a local store expert to see what they can find.

Comment: Does this happen only after some time that the computer was turned-on, or can it arrive on the first boot of the day?